# react, detectar fallo de build con bash en windows

Tags: reactjs, bash

tengo el siguiente codigo bash para pushear la build de react al repo. Sucede que aveces la build falla por distintos motivos. Y quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de luego de hacer el npm run build, detectar si la build fue exitosa o no y si no fue exitosa, detener el script.

```
set -e

npm run build

git add -A

git commit -m "Build"

git push -f
```

Comment: ¿qué tipo de errores te salen? Muy probablemente podrías mirar `$?`, que te dará 0 si todo fue bien y un número diferente si no fue así.

Comment: aveces sucede que me olvido de cambiar la version de node (con nvm) porque tambien trabajo en otros proyectos. Y cuando hago la build falla diciendo que la version de node no es la correcta. En fin, no me interesa el tipo de error que de, sino que se detenga el script. Podrias mostrarme o pasarme algun link de como mirar el $?
Gracias

Comment: bueno de hecho mirando un poco más, con tu `set -e` ya estaría haciendo lo mismo, pues esta orden lo que hace es matar el script en caso que algún comando se ejecute y dé un resultado diferente a 0. Por ejemplo, en tu script actual si escribes algo así como `blabla` después de `set -e`, será un comando incorrecto y ya no hará nada más. Con esto quiero decir que si `npm` sale con un código erróneo, tu código ya forzará el término del script.

Comment: mmm ok, igual tengo mis dudas, voy a checkear el script y el proyecto, voy a hacer pruebas, porque resulta que luego de fallar la build, sigue, y me lo pushea al repo...